# How to access a hash that has a key that's an array and a value that's an integer

Tags: ruby

So I have a hash that looks like:

`hash = { ["1", "2", "3"]=>"a", ["4", "5", "6"]=>"b", ["7", "8", "9"]=>"c" }`

Though when I try to do something like `hash[0]` just a new line in my console shows up and if I try `hash[0][0]` it pops me an error that says [] method is undefined.

Now I'm wondering how to I access this in a way that I can do something like `hash["1"]` and it'll return me the `"a"`.

I assume that since it lets me make hashes in this way I can access the content inside.

Comment: sorry; you'll have to do `hash[["1", "2", "3"]]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure why you would want to create a hash with a key that's an array, but it works :)

```
hash = { ["1", "2", "3"]=>"a", ["4", "5", "6"]=>"b", ["7", "8", "9"]=>"c" }

hash[["1", "2", "3"]]
=> "a"
```

You might want to consider the opposite:

```
hash = { "a"=>["1", "2", "3"], "b"=>["4", "5", "6"], "c"=>["7", "8", "9"] }

hash["a"]
=> ["1", "2", "3"]
```

Answer (score 2):

There's not a direct built-in way to access something like this, but by using `select` you can filter out the key/value pair that has the "1" and get the value for it:

```
hash.select { |key| key.include?("1") }.values.first
```

This assumes that each integer only exists in a single key.